# sudo su not asking password even after changing password

Tags: ubuntu, security, passwords, sudo

I have an ubuntu instance on AWS.
After getting ssh login, I was able to change to root password with `sudo su` command.
For security reasons, I wanted to change the root password.
So I tried the following :

```
root@email:/home/ubuntu# sudo passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@email:/home/ubuntu#
```

After changing password when I try to `sudo su`, it doesnt asks for password

```
ubuntu@email:~$ sudo su
root@email:/home/ubuntu#
```

Whereas, when I try only `su`, it prompts for one:

```
ubuntu@email:~$ su
Password:
```

How to implement security or set a password for `sudo su`?

Following are the details of sudoers (visudo)

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: `sudo -k` also doesn't prompts for password. adding content of sudoers file in the question.

Comment: Yup. Even after, `sudo -k`, `sudo su` isnt prompting for a password.

Comment: nope, `sudo ls` is also not asking password:(

Comment: It'll be nice if whoever you're replying to could leave the asked questions here so others can see your progress.

Comment: PEBKAC error:  `su` never asks for a password when it is run by root.  Since you are running `sudo` first, `su` is run as root.  Never run `sudo su`.  If you want a root shell, run `sudo -s`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line in your `sudoers` file

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

makes it include other files from `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory. It may seem the line is commented out but it's not; the directive is `#includedir` with leading `#`. One of these included files probably sets a rule with `NOPASSWD` that causes the issue.

Before you change something, make sure your regular user has a valid nonempty password. From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281085/693277):

> `sudo` will ask for a password even when you don't have one, and won't accept an empty password.

When in doubt, invoke `passwd` and set a brand new password for your regular user.

This command should tell you which file(s) you need to inspect:

```
sudo grep -r NOPASSWD /etc/sudoers.d/
```

The line you seek may look like this:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment it out (`# ubuntu ALL=...`). Compare [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/525681/693277).

Comment: Is it bad to remove `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`? Here's my question for more context: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309979/is-it-bad-to-remove-includedir-etc-sudoers-d-using-visudo

Comment: @pir: you may run into troubles... https://askubuntu.com/q/1407218/571173